# run Jquery function when window size greater than 800

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

i do some greensock and scrollmagic animation. I put this animation inside a function called scrollMgc. this animation will run when the window width greater than 800px and will stop when the window less than 800px on resize. This the code i wrote so far

```
function scrollMgc(){

    // Prepare the stage
    TweenMax.set($('.animation-awards'), {y: 70});

    // Make scrollmagic controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    // Create awards scene
    var awardScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '.awards',
        triggerHook: 0.8,
        duration: '270%'
    })
    .setTween(TweenMax.to('.animation-awards', 1, {y: '-=300'}))
    .addIndicators({})
    .addTo(controller);

}

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width > 800){
        scrollMgc();
    }
    else{
        scrollMgc = undefined;
    }
})
```

Can anybody help me out of this issue?

Comment: this the code i wrote so far? So what is the issue you are facing what is the expected outcome etc. And please create a demo that helps explain the issue and the outcome.

Comment: instead of "stopping" you are deleting the function here: `scrollMgc = undefined;`

Comment: i want the function run when the screen width greater than 800px, and i want the function don't run when i resize the screen to less than 800px, that is why i used .resize(). The issue is the function still running when i resize down the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below as width is a function:

```
if($(this).width() > 800){
   scrollMgc();
}
else{
   scrollMgc = undefined;
}
```

Comment: i still don't get it

Comment: Okay then try $(window).width();. This is working correctly in me.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).width is a function.

```
$(this).width()
```